# Json file parsing - Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

For our test data we are going to maintain the test data in JSON format, and below is the sample JSON file.

```
{
    "INV": [
        {
            "TestCaseID": "APL",
            "TestData": [
                {
                    "INVLabel": "Title",
                    "Controltype": "text",
                    "Inputvalues": "solid state device"
                },
                {
                    "INVLabel": "Inventor",
                    "Controltype": "search",
                    "Inputvalues": "Sabra-Anne Truesdale"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "TestCaseID": "APL1",
            "TestData": [
                {
                    "INVLabel": "Title",
                    "Controltype": "text",
                    "Inputvalues": " "
                },
                {
                    "INVLabel": "Inventor",
                    "Controltype": "search",
                    "Inputvalues": "jenifer"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

using JsonSlurper how can I retrieve test data based on the test case id?.
initially, I planned to convert the JSON into Map Object from that I tried. but it's not working as expected. can anyone please guide me to retrieve these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `find()` method on the `INV` node with a closure `{ it.TestCaseID == 'ID'}` to get the first element from the list. Consider the following example that extracts the test data for the id `APL1`.

```groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def input = '''{
    "INV": [
        {
            "TestCaseID": "APL",
            "TestData": [
                {
                    "INVLabel": "Title",
                    "Controltype": "text",
                    "Inputvalues": "solid state device"
                },
                {
                    "INVLabel": "Inventor",
                    "Controltype": "search",
                    "Inputvalues": "Sabra-Anne Truesdale"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "TestCaseID": "APL1",
            "TestData": [
                {
                    "INVLabel": "Title",
                    "Controltype": "text",
                    "Inputvalues": " "
                },
                {
                    "INVLabel": "Inventor",
                    "Controltype": "search",
                    "Inputvalues": "jenifer"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(input)

def testData = json.INV.find { it.TestCaseID == 'APL1' }.TestData

println testData
```

Output:

```
[[INVLabel:Title, Controltype:text, Inputvalues: ], [INVLabel:Inventor, Controltype:search, Inputvalues:jenifer]]
```

Comment: Thank you, Using parsing with the file I got the below error -org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.json.internal.LazyMap)

Comment: :my code - @Keyword
 def getTestData(fileName){
  def inputFile = new File(fileName)
  def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)
  def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(InputJSON)
  def testData = json.INV.find { it.TestCaseID == 'APL' }.TestData
  println testData
 }

Comment: Instead of `JsonSlurper.parseText()`, you can use `parse()` method with a file - `new JsonSlurper().parse(new File(fileName))`.